# Configure Protocols using iptables log file with ndpi

Tags: linux, iptables, logging, network-protocols

I am using iptables with ndpi to filter my network and add two rules to my iptables rules

they are

```
iptables -I INPUT -m ndpi --http -j LOG
iptables -I INPUT -m ndpi --google -j LOG
```

In my log file I can't configure which log is for http and google protocols

Comment: It pays to read the manual.  `man iptables-extensions` in most distributions will get it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can distinguish your log entries with `--log-prefix`. For instance:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m ndpi --google -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables INPUT: User went to Google: "
```

Remember to leave a space at the end of the prefix text, as it is prepended exactly as-is.